# Trying to compile my first program in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I am getting compiler issue when trying to compile a simple test program on erlang. I have tried both on mac os x (lion) and windows 7 (64)

```
~module(tut).
~export([double/1]).

double (N) ->
N*2.
```

I have checked that the file is named correctly and the correct modules seem to be installed I am using the otp_win64_R16B on my windows machine. I get the following error on both platforms

```
16> c(tut).  
tut.erl:1: syntax error before: '~'
tut.erl:2: syntax error before: '~'
tut.erl:4: no module definition
tut.erl:4: Warning: function double/1 is unused
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it should be: `-module` and `-export`, with the `-` not with `~`.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace ~ with -. Please take a try.